# How to I remove duplicates but retain the original value in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a Google App script for Google Sheets that removes duplicates from a given range. I have successfully created a script that removes duplicate values, but what I would like it to do is retain one of the values, at present it clears out everything including the "original" record.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function removeDuplicates() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master");
    var rng = sheet.getRange("H2:H")
    var data = rng.getValues();
    var newData = new Array();
    for(i in data){
        var row = data[i];
        var duplicate = false;
        for(j in newData){
            if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
                duplicate = true;
            }
        }
        if(!duplicate){
            newData.push(row);
        }
    }
    rng.clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: I can't recreate your problem. With column H full of only `8`s, if I run your script, only one `8` gets pasted in column A, so it _is_ maintaining an "original" record of the duplicated value.

Comment: Hi Diego, that's strange. In My sheet it is now deleting the entire column contents!

Comment: Yes, well you're clearing the content in column H with your second-to-last line.

Comment: Check A1 in sheet